# getBBox() vs getBoundingClientRect() vs getClientRects()

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I am unable to find an explicit reference for the use of these functions:
`getBBox()` vs `getBoundingClientRect()` vs `getClientRects()`.

Could you explain what they do and what are the coordinates (and their referential) they return?

Comment: The explicit reference for `getBoundingClientRect` at least is easy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score 50):

**getBBox** is defined in the [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox) it returns coordinates in the *local* coordinate system after the application of transforms.

**getBoundingClientRect** and **getClientRects** are defined in the [CSSOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-element-getboundingclientrect). Their main difference is that they return coordinates in the *outer* SVG coordinate system.

getBoundingClientRect returns a single rect that is the union of all the rects that getClientRect would return.

Comment: So, what is the difference between "getBoundingClientRect and getClientRects"

Comment: `getBBox(options)` for SVG elements also allows you to choose if you want to include the fill, stroke, markers, clipping of the SVG element in the boundary, which might be relevant. (These options [are not there in SVG 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox), but [are in the current draft for SVG 2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/types.html#__svg__SVGGraphicsElement__getBBox))

Answer (score 36):

**some** elements(like `span` tag) will have multiple *ClientRects* when they are wrapped into multiple lines.<sup>[MDN Element.getClientRects()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects)</sup>
and a *BoundingRect* is the **union** of *ClientRects* of a element.<sup>[MDN Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)</sup>

Answer (score 29):

This is an example I copied from MDN [Element.getClientRects()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects) and I added `addBoundingClientRectOverlay` function to compare `addClientRectsOverlay`.
You can see the red rectangle is from `getClientRects` and the black dash rectangle is from `getBoundingClientRect`, so you can tell what's different.
[image]

```js
function addClientRectsOverlay(elt) {
  // Absolutely position a div over each client rect so that its border width
  // is the same as the rectangle's width.
  // Note: the overlays will be out of place if the user resizes or zooms.
  var rects = elt.getClientRects();

  for (var i = 0; i != rects.length; i++) {
    var rect = rects[i];
    var tableRectDiv = document.createElement("div");
    tableRectDiv.style.position = "absolute";
    tableRectDiv.style.border = "1px solid red";
    var scrollTop =
      document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    var scrollLeft =
      document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft;
    tableRectDiv.style.margin = tableRectDiv.style.padding = "0";
    tableRectDiv.style.top = rect.top + scrollTop + "px";
    tableRectDiv.style.left = rect.left + scrollLeft + "px"; // we want rect.width to be the border width, so content width is 2px less.
    tableRectDiv.style.width = rect.width - 2 + "px";
    tableRectDiv.style.height = rect.height - 2 + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(tableRectDiv);
  }
}
function addBoundingClientRectOverlay(elt) {
  // Absolutely position a div over each client rect so that its border width
  // is the same as the rectangle's width.
  // Note: the overlays will be out of place if the user resizes or zooms.
  var rect = elt.getBoundingClientRect();

  var tableRectDiv = document.createElement("div");
  tableRectDiv.style.position = "absolute";
  tableRectDiv.style.border = "1px dashed #321";
  var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  var scrollLeft =
    document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollLeft;
  tableRectDiv.style.margin = tableRectDiv.style.padding = "0";
  tableRectDiv.style.top = rect.top + scrollTop+1 + "px";
  tableRectDiv.style.left = rect.left + scrollLeft+1 + "px"; // we want rect.width to be the border width, so content width is 2px less.
  tableRectDiv.style.width = rect.width - 4 + "px";
  tableRectDiv.style.height = rect.height - 4 + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(tableRectDiv);
}
(function() {
  /* call function addClientRectsOverlay(elt) for all elements with assigned css class "withClientRectsOverlay"  */
  var elt = document.getElementsByClassName("withClientRectsOverlay");
  for (var i = 0; i < elt.length; i++) {
    addClientRectsOverlay(elt[i]);
    addBoundingClientRectOverlay(elt[i]);
  }
})();
```

```css
strong {
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}
div p,
ol,
table {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
span,
li,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects -->

<h3>A paragraph with a span inside</h3>
<p>Both the span and the paragraph have a border set. The client rects are in red. Note that the p has only one border box, while the span has multiple border boxes.</p>

<div>
 <strong>Original</strong>
 <p>
  <span>Paragraph that spans multiple lines</span>
 </p>
</div>
 
<div>
 <strong>p's rect</strong>
 <p class="withClientRectsOverlay">
  <span>Paragraph that spans multiple lines</span>
 </p>
</div>

<div>
 <strong>span's rect</strong>
 <p>
  <span class="withClientRectsOverlay">Paragraph that spans multiple lines</span>
 </p>
</div><h3>A list</h3>
<p>Note that the border box doesn't include the number, so neither do the client rects.</p>

<div>
 <strong>Original</strong>
 <ol>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
 </ol>
</div>

<div>
 <strong>ol's rect</strong>
 <ol class="withClientRectsOverlay">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
 </ol>
</div>

<div>
 <strong>each li's rect</strong>
 <ol>
  <li class="withClientRectsOverlay">Item 1</li>
  <li class="withClientRectsOverlay">Item 2</li>
 </ol>
</div><h3>A table with a caption</h3>
<p>Although the table's border box doesn't include the caption, the client rects do include the caption.</p>

<div>
 <strong>Original</strong>
 <table>
  <caption>caption</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>thead</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>tbody</td></tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
 
<div>
 <strong>table's rect</strong>
 <table class="withClientRectsOverlay">
  <caption>caption</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>thead</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>tbody</td></tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```